# Nodejs message queue vs macrotask queue

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the difference between *message queue* and *macrotask queue*? Is it the same thing?

On Nodejs documentation [here](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-event-loop#the-message-queue) it says:

> When setTimeout() is called, the Browser or Node.js starts the timer. Once the timer expires, in this case immediately as we put 0 as the timeout, the callback function is put in the Message Queue.

While, in [this](https://nodejs.dev/learn/understanding-setimmediate) section, it says:

> A setTimeout, setImmediate callback is added to macrotask queue

So, does *message queue* and *macrotask queue* is the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am reading this right, it seems the "Message Queue" is a general term that is implemented using a few different queues.

In [this](https://nodejs.dev/learn/understanding-setimmediate) section they explain:

> A process.nextTick callback is added to process.nextTick queue. A
> Promise.then() callback is added to promises microtask queue. A
> setTimeout, setImmediate callback is added to macrotask queue.

Looks like the macrotask, microtask, etc. are specific parts of the implementation and have different attributes.

For example, execution order:

> Event loop executes tasks in process.nextTick queue first, and then
> executes promises microtask queue, and then executes macrotask queue.

Found another easy explanation [here](https://medium.com/@Rahulx1/understanding-event-loop-call-stack-event-job-queue-in-javascript-63dcd2c71ecd).

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the same thing here. One could say that "[message queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue)" is a more general term, as in "*the microtask queue and the macrotask queue are both message queues*".